# Remove Team in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode4

I´d like to remove a team which appears in Xcode (Device section).

I have removed the projects assigned to that team, I have removed the provisionings profiles assigned to that team and I rebooted Xcode.

But still the team is there (Device section).

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried removing the team certificate from within Keychain Assistant?

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try the next monday and will tell you :). Thanks

Comment: Fine!! it was perfect!!! 

Only a detail, if you are not sure about the certificate you are looking for deleting, in the keychain Assistant, certificates section, you can select one and in the options menu select: get information ( obtener informacion, in spanish menu).

thanks a lot.

Comment: kante, please use the answer box to answer your own question, then accept that answer as correct.  That way, SO won't show your question as still needing an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a team I'm no longer associated with?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565129/how-to-remove-a-team-im-no-longer-associated-with)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are removed as a developer in developer.apple.com from the team.