# Force Flutter to manually select iOS team

Tags: flutter

Recently I had to replace my SSD, and when tried to backup something went wrong so I had to format it and make a fresh install.
The problem is that I didn't export my keys so now I'm using new team ID and I set it manually in Xcode, but when I build from Android Studio it manages automatically the signing options and choice the old team ID.

So my question is how to force flutter to use the new dev team?
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16614479/10659482

Comment: nope, still saying "Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: teamID2"